# Loop through a table and change the content of cells

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through the cells of a table (for a specific row) and change the values of the cells. The cell elements (td) or the row element (tr) doesn't have any class or id.

This is what I do:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "._cancel_btn",function(e){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each (function() {
    var cellText = $(this).html();
    alert(cellText) // gives me the current value in td
  });
```

How can I replace the content of each cell while iterating through the row's td?

Comment: what do you want to replace with?

Comment: like `$(this).text("hello");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go whit this:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "._cancel_btn",function(e){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each (function() {
    var cellText = $(this).html();
    alert(cellText) // gives me the current value in td
    $(this).text("YOUR NEW TEXT");
  });
})
```